# nexti gdb with _GetStdHandle@4 finishes the program

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb, nasm, 32-bit

Here is the asm x86 code on windows 10, it puts an ascii char in memory and prints it with WriteFile.

file.asm :

```
global _main
extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ExitProcess@4

section .text
_main:  
    mov al, 8
    add al, '0'

    mov [message], al

    push -11
    call _GetStdHandle@4

    push 0
    push 0
    push 1
    push message
    push eax
    call _WriteFile@20

    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4

section .bss
    message resb 1
```

Commands :

```
nasm -fwin32 file.asm
gcc file.obj
a.exe
```

It prints `8`. I want to inspect the changes in registers with each instruction on `gdb`.

I do the following :

```
gdb a.exe
```

Then, in gdb :

```
b main
run
nexti
i r
nexti
i r
nexti
i r
nexti
i r
```

It works well, but when the position is just before the `call _GetStdHandle@4` and I do a `nexti` again, it continues all the program and finishes.
I have to put a break just after the call. It seems `_GetStdHandle@4` modifies some register (for instance `EAX`) so I wanted to do `nexti` without stepping into.

I've tested a custom `call` with a `ret` and here the `nexti` works correctly.

1. Why does the program finishes when I do a `nexti` on the `call _GetStdHandle@4` instruction ?
2. How can I make the `nexti` works as it have to ?